# Error on update-database efcore asp.net core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
namespace LoopSquad.Core.Entities.Addresses
{
    public class Address
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string NoName { get; set; }
        public string AddressL1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressL2 { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customers.Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Jobs.Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace LoopSquad.Core.Entities.Customers
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FKCustomerType")]
        public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
        public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Addresses.Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    }

}

namespace LoopSquad.Core.Entities.Jobs
{
    public class Job
    {
        [Key]
        public int JobId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FKCustomer")]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customers.Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FKAddress")]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Addresses.Address Address { get; set; }


        public DateTime BookedDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FKUser")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public Users.ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FRoomLayout")]
        public int RoomLayoutId { get; set; }
        public RoomLayout RoomLayout { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FKJobType")]
        public int JobTypeId { get; set; }
        public JobType JobType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FKLoopType")]
        public int loopTypeId { get; set; }
        public LoopType LoopType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FKJobStatus")]
        public int JobStatusId { get; set; }
        public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what error do you get

Comment: Code was formated honest

Comment: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Jobs_Customers_CustomerId' on table 'Jobs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
PM>

Comment: Failed executing DbCommand (24ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Jobs] (
    [JobId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [CustomerId] int NOT NULL,
    [AddressId] int NOT NULL,
    [BookedDateTime] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,

Comment: [ApplicationUserId] nvarchar(450) NULL,
    [RoomLayoutId] int NOT NULL,
    [JobTypeId] int NOT NULL,
    [loopTypeId] int NOT NULL,

Comment: [JobStatusId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Jobs] PRIMARY KEY ([JobId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Jobs_Addresses_AddressId] FOREIGN KEY ([AddressId])

Comment: Don't add the error as comment. Please add into the question and not here. Please Read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your problem and it is because you enable cascade delete by default which will result in cycles for your relationships.

Try to disable it using `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` in dbcontext, for example

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }      

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasOne(p => p.Customer)
                                  .WithMany()
                                  .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId)
                                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete